# Comparing times php and same database call from php and ajax?

Tags: mysql, ajax, time

I have a little concern and don't know how tight the security is involving it.

I have on my webpage a structure which is set up as follows;

A php include with a function for the whole layout and before this a database call that is fired if it meets a certain time criteria such as:

```
if (strtotime($user['active']) + 60 * 15 <= time()) {
     $q ...
}
function pageLayout () {
     content();
     echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://"></script>';
}
```

And then on each page I have a content function

```
require('include.php');
function content () {
     ...
}
pageLayout();
```

The problem is that the database call in the include can also be fired by using ajax in my javascript file (which is called at the bottom of the page) if it meets the certain criteria to do so based on a page timer which is the exact same criteria for the first.

What are the chances of it firing in the include and then in the ajax call? Is it possible that the first query will not update the date fast enough disabling it in the javascript therefore enabling it to also fire in the javascript ajax?

The query must only be called once, as on a successfull query the current date is inserted meaning the user has to wait 15 minutes again. And if it fires twice that means the user will be getting 2 updates which should be 30mins not 15!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

never tried that, but I think put the query in query.php and call it via include_once could work.